# web_1 | Error: dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker-compose

I have a Django Project. I have dockerized this project to run as container.

Currently when I run this container using following command it shows following error at the end and exited

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-stag-prod.yaml up -d
```

**Docker Logs Output**

```
web_1  | Starting Gunicorn server...
web_1  | 2023-12-05 18:20:18 [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.17.4
web_1  | 2023-12-05 18:20:18 [1] [INFO] Listening at:
http://0.0.0.0:8000
(1)
web_1  | 2023-12-05 18:20:18 [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.10/os.py:1030: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
web_1  |   return io.open(fd, mode, buffering, encoding, *args, **kwargs)
web_1  | 2023-12-05 18:20:18 [6] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6
web_1  | 2023-12-05 18:20:18 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
web_1  | 2023-12-05 18:20:18 [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
web_1  | 2023-12-05 18:20:18 [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
web_1  |
web_1  | Error: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I am not able to identify the line which is causing error. How can I identify the line number or code snippet which is causing issue.

Also my application is running inside container using gunicorn

```
exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:${PORT:-8000} --timeout 300 -w 4 -t 4 wtools2.wsgi:application
```